How to delimit text in R into columns of a dataframe?
I have this text that I have been trying to split into 3 columns of a Dataframe but have not been able to.
library(tidyverse)

txt <- '[1] "TRIGLYCERIDES SERUM|115.3|Normal : Upto 150 Border Line mg/dl"'

Separator in above is |
I have tried below code but it didn't work.
txt %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  separate_wider_delim(.,delim = "|",
                       names = c("Test Name","Result","Unit"))

output:
Error in `separate_wider_delim()`:
! `cols` is absent but must be supplied.
Backtrace:
 1. txt %>% data.frame() %>% ...
 2. tidyr::separate_wider_delim(., delim = "|", names = c("Test Name", "Result", "Unit"))

Also tried this but didn't work:
txt |> 
  read.csv(text = _, check.names = FALSE, sep = "|")

Not sure what's wrong.

Don't use a dot, try tibble(txt) %>% separate_wider_delim(txt, "|", names=c("Test Name","Result","Unit")), where txt is the column name.

Yes this works well. In my complete code case this will work some code %>% as.tibble() %>% separate_wider_delim(value, delim = "|",names = c("Test Name","Result","Unit"))
I will accept your answer if you will post it as Answer. Thanks for your help.
